# Experiment of drawing a point uniformly at random

Tags: probability

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $P\left([a,b]\right) = b-a$, $[a,b] \subset \Omega$. Define $Z = Z(\omega) = e^{\omega}$. Find $P(Z \leq t)$ for all real values $t$?

So far, this is what I came up with: $Z$ on $\Omega = [0,1]$ is the exponential function increasing from $1$ to $e$. $P(Z \leq t) = P(e^{\omega} \leq t) = P(\omega \leq \log t)$. And this is where I'm stuck. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: All right.Farther you must consider several cases, when t>1, 0<t<1, t<0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking in the right direction.

To be discerned are the cases:

$t\leq1$ then $\{\omega\in[0,1]\mid e^{\omega}\leq t\}=\varnothing$
so that $P(Z\leq t)=0$

$1<t\leq e$ then $\{\omega\in[0,1]\mid e^{\omega}\leq t\}=[0,\ln t]$
so that $P(Z\leq t)=\ln t$

$t>e$ then $\{\omega\in[0,1]\mid e^{\omega}\leq t\}=[0,1]$ so that
$P(Z\leq t)=1$

Comment: I got your idea, but shouldn't the first case be `t<=1`, cuz for instance for `t=1/2`, there is no `omega` from `[0,1]`, such that `e^(omega) <= 1/2`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry, I will repair.